# Java RMI Implementation

Tags: java, server, raspberry-pi, client-server, rmi

I have a typical client & server situation where I want the client be able to call methods from objects running on the server. I use the Java RMI to solve this situation.

The serverside code is below and it compiles and runs fine:

ServerInt.java

```
package gpio.control;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface ServerInt extends Remote{
    public void setHeizung(boolean x) throws RemoteException;
    public void quitError() throws RemoteException;
    public void startPWM(int periode,int pulsbreite,int pulsanzahl) throws RemoteException;
}
```

ServerImpl.java

```
package gpio.control;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.RemoteServer;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class ServerImpl implements ServerInt{
    private Model myModel;

    public ServerImpl(Model m) throws RemoteException {
        myModel = m;

        LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
        ServerInt stub = (ServerInt) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(this, 1099);
        RemoteServer.setLog(System.out);

        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        registry.rebind("Server1", stub);
    }

    @Override
    public void setHeizung(boolean x) throws RemoteException {
        myModel.setHeizung(x);
    }

    @Override
    public void quitError() throws RemoteException {
        myModel.quitError();
    }

    @Override
    public void startPWM(int periode, int pulsbreite, int pulsanzahl) throws RemoteException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I also created a small client application which runs on the same server as the server application:

Client.java

```
package client;

import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        ServerInt serverint = (ServerInt) registry.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/Server1"); 
        serverint.setHeizung(true);
    }

}
```

When I run the Client program now, I get the following errors:
Error from Client:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.rmi.NotBoundException: rmi://localhost:1099/Server1
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:166)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:410)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:268)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$241(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:276)
    at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:253)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:379)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at client.Client.main(Client.java:12)
```

Error from server:

```
Sep 07, 2016 9:47:04 AM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCall
FINER: RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1: sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl[0:0:0, 0]: void rebind(java.lang.String, java.rmi.Remote)]
Sep 07, 2016 9:47:04 AM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCall
FINER: RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1: sun.rmi.transport.DGCImpl[0:0:0, 2]: java.rmi.dgc.Lease dirty(java.rmi.server.ObjID[], long, java.rmi.dgc.Lease)]
Sep 07, 2016 9:47:05 AM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCall
FINER: RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1: sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl[0:0:0, 0]: java.rmi.Remote lookup(java.lang.String)]
Sep 07, 2016 9:47:05 AM sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef logCallException
FINE: RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1: [127.0.0.1] exception:
java.rmi.NotBoundException: rmi://localhost:1099/Server1
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.lookup(RegistryImpl.java:166)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:410)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:268)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$241(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @Mr_Thorynque No he doesn't, and there is nothing here to suggest otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In Client.java change

```
registry.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/Server1")
```

to

```
registry.lookup("Server1");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `Registry` rather than `Naming` to do the lookup, you should omit the URL part of the lookup string, just as you did when binding. You should just lookup `Server1`, just as you did when binding.

Comment: I changed it to "Server1" but after doing so I received a UnmarshalException: "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException gpio.control.ServerInt (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)

So I added  System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager()); to the Client & Server but now I get a AccessControlException

Comment: So you have a solution to that problem and you now have a different problem. Adding a `SecurityManager` isn't the solution to that one, at least not by itself. Deploying the class named is the solution.